# Change checkUpkeep function returns arguments

Tags: chainlink, chainlink-keepers

Can I modify the `returns` statement to include `a bool [] memory` instead of just `bool` ?

Comment: Could you add your other question as a separate stack exchange ETH or stackoverflow question?

Comment: I finally found the quickest way to find you hehehe; Buidling something cool rn :D !

Comment: stackoverflow and stack exchange are amazing since they are indexed by web crawlers, the more questions we get on forums the more likely people can solve problems with a simple web search!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.

The Chainlink node is looking for a specific return type, if you change the interface the nodes won't be sure that's the function they should be calling.

That being said, you *can* change what checkupkeep returns, just a chainlink keeper node wouldn't be able to call checkupkeeps.